Questions about the Bitcoin market are off-topic here, right?
Looking here
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
and here
Are questions about trading on-topic?
I conclude that questions about the Bitcoin market are off-topic here, right? I'm not talking about investment advice - more things like "are there multiple Bitcoin markets? Do we buy Bitcoin as a currency or as stocks of some fund?" etc. Still, if I understand correctly, this site is about Bitcoin techonology, not about the economics of Bitcoin. 

I would say that any bitcoin-specific question is on topic if it follows the other guidelines like not being opinion based or discussing future price trends.

Thanks, then I may post my question here next time.
